# optimize the performance of informix stored procudure in asp.net application?

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I want to know how to use the equivalent to :

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
```

AND

```
WITH RECOMPILE option
```

in informix stored procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SET ARITHABORT ON 
>   **Sql Server manual says** : Terminates a query when an overflow or
>   divide-by-zero error occurs during query execution.

At Informix , by default, any error occurred during the execution of any UDR/SP (procedure or function) will trigger an exception and this will be automatically raised at user session level. This will include any arithmetic error.

What you can do inside of SPLs is the inverse , include a treatment to not allow this exception reach the scope of user session.
For this read about [ON EXCEPTION](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/topic/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_514.htm)

> [WITH RECOMPILE option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) 
>   **Sql Server manual says** :  Creating a stored procedure that specifies
>   the WITH RECOMPILE option in its definition indicates that SQL Server
>   does not cache a plan for this stored procedure; the stored procedure
>   is recompiled each time it is executed. Use the WITH RECOMPILE option
>   when stored procedures take parameters whose values differ widely
>   between executions of the stored procedure, resulting in different
>   execution plans to be created each time. Use of this option is
>   uncommon and causes the stored procedure to execute more slowly,
>   because the stored procedure must be recompiled each time it is
>   executed.

At Informix the similar solution is run : `update statistics for procedure <your_proc>;`
Check the explanation at [Informix Manual here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0176.htm)

Comment: +1: Your analysis of ARITHABORT is good.  There isn't really a direct analogue to WITH RECOMPILE in Informix.  If you're working with temporary tables in the procedure, it is reoptimized each time anyway, but that's an implementation by-product rather than a design feature.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, looking for this information on manual I found nothing about UDR + temp tables = automatic reoptimization. Please, what you means with "implementation by-product" ?

Comment: It's normally regarded as...well, calling it a bug might be too strong, but calling it a not altogether desirable by-product of the way that temporary tables are handled in SPL, rather than a desirable feature, is reasonably accurate.  That's probably why it isn't documented.  And simply creating (and dropping) a temporary table in the stored procedure to achieve WITH RECOMPILE isn't really a good coding style, for all it might work.  It would limit the places where you can use the stored procedure, too.  You'd need to consider exception handling in the code, too.

Comment: @Jonathan thank's for this detailed information. Just to better understand, the use of a temporary table (any DML) into SPL as included in this behave (reoptimization) or is limited to create/drop statements?

Comment: Any use of a temporary table, AFAICR,